# Can one change his minhag to another (equally stringent) minhag?

Tags: minhag, mesorah-tradition

This has probably been asked before, but I couldn't find the question:

Can one change his minhag to another, equally stringent, minhag (without doing hataras nedarim)? So for example: if one ties his tzitzis a certain way, can he change that style to a different way of tying tzitzis?

How "weak" would the minhag have to be? For example: the nusach one davens in is a hundreds-years-old minhag, and usually well sourced. Whereas wearing a black hat is much newer and (as far as I know) arbitrary. There is a wide spectrum of minhagim, (both between and beyond these two). Where would the line be drawn?

Comment: Does 'wearing a black hat' (as opposed to wearing a double head covering in general) qualify as a minhag?

Comment: @יהושעק maybe not, but it's definitely a tradition that's been passed down for a few generations. But that's the point- it would be on the weaker side of the "minhag spectrum"